# Pending sugested edit in the queue

Tags: bug

I already have a pending suggested edit in the queue. So when I try to edit another post I get a very basic HTML page as follows:

[image]

Has it been purposefully left as it is?

It's not a bug. I am just pointing out that the page lacks formatting.

Comment: The post you have showing up there has a pending suggested edit at the moment. Why do you think that's a bug?

Comment: @Oded The page doesn't has a front end.I didn't know what tags to add to this question

Comment: It is not clear what you think the bug is from your phrasing. Please clarify.

Comment: @Oded Its not a bug.Its just that page without any front end strikes odd.So I am just pointing it out in case the front end developers team forgot to format that page.

Comment: When you open the like from Incognito (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36680051/edit) you see what they are talking about (No html, just a plain text response from the server - Error 503)

Comment: Is this a tag wiki? If it is, it may actually be a review suspension.